# wordpress pagination, links appear but go nowhere when clicked

Tags: wordpress, pagination

My problem is that, although the links do appear on the bottom of the page where I place the function that calls the pagination.

when clicked, the page does nothing.

I've found countless similar questions on the web (many here on SO ) but when I try to implement 
those posts resolutions, the same thing happens. ALL the different pagination methods,loops,functions....and EVEN plugins that I try WORK in that they **appear** on the page but when clicked, the URL changes accordingly but the page content doesn't change.

So as an example, I'm using this loop that I found in an "accepted answer" from someone elses question here on SO

```
function pagination($pages = '', $range = 3){ 
    $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;
    global $paged; if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;
    if($pages == '') {
        global $wp_query; $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages; if(!$pages)
    { $pages = 1; } 
}

 if(1 != $pages) { echo "<div class='pagination'><span>Page ".$paged." of ".$pages."</span>";
     if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) {
         echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'>&laquo; First</a>";
     }
     if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages) {
         echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>&lsaquo; Previous</a>";
     }

     for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++){
          if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems )){
               echo ($paged == $i)? "<span class='current'>".$i."</span>":"<a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class='inactive'>".$i."</a>";
        } 

     }

      if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."'>Next &rsaquo;</a>";
     if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>Last &raquo;</a>";
     echo "</div>n"; }
 }
```

and applied the function call to the bottom of my post loop under the endwhile//if so that it doesn't repeat through each post shown on the page, and again, it shows (just like all the others)
but the page itself doesn't do anything.

My question is, with this type of a problem where the links are showing up and all types of different versions I've tried, **do** appear on the page but when clicked, go nowhere, what is it I could be missing?

Do I need to enable pagination somewhere like the way one enables widgets or..or do my pages have to have any type of hook or ..... like when one inserts "" etc...

I'm at a loss.

Comment: I've had this problem before. Are you trying to get pagination to work for a custom post type?

Comment: yes sir. @ Coletrain lol, nice name btw lol. But yeah i am using custom post type which after trying to many, im wondering am i missing something somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem. Also I am using [kriesi](http://www.kriesi.at/archives/how-to-build-a-wordpress-post-pagination-without-plugin) pagination function but you can switch out the if (function_exists("pagination"))  with the default wordpress older and newer function.

```
// Backup the original property value
$backup_page_total = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
// Copy the custom query property to the $wp_query object
$wp_query->max_num_pages = $loop->max_num_pages;
?>
<!-- now show the paging links -->
<?php if (function_exists("pagination")) {pagination($additional_loop->max_num_pages);} ?>
<?php
// Finally restore the $wp_query property to it's original value
$wp_query->max_num_pages = $backup_page_total;
?>
```

Comment: hey @coletrain, i dont see a function so does this mean i place this at the pages that i want pagination to occur, or do i copy/paste this to the functions.php as is? i mean i see the "if function exist, i assume i put that on my actual page under the post loop, but does it ALL go there, or only that if line and all else in the functions.php?

Comment: I meant remove `<?php if (function_exists("pagination")){pagination($additional_loop->max_num_pages);} ?>` if you're not using that function if you do decided to use it you can follow the tutorial linked above and if not just replace that code with the default wordpress newer and older code. Place the above code in your custom post type archive page.

Comment: Hey Coletrain, i tried that tutorial twice and the same thing happens, Ive tried other ones and i even went into the twenty eleven theme, ripped their pagination function, added it to mine, and called it from my page and the same thing happened. To give you an example, here is the site im working on http://www.somdowprod.net/4testing/campanita/?page_id=18 , I've set the post count per page to 3 so that it builds the bottom page links, youll see the numbers below the final(3rd post) but when you click them, they just jump up to the top of the page but with the same content. The postsDont update

Comment: @somdow another tip is to update your permalink structure. I notice you are not using `/%postname%/`. Another thing is to make sure you have rewrite set to true and has_archive for your custom post type. Let me know if that helps

Comment: Hey Coletrain, i changed the permalink structure to "postname" and still the same thing. I looked into "custom post type" but i dont mess with that, i just mess with the basic categories and pull the content via calling the category in my loop, for example (query_posts('category_name=kids-books'). Not sure whats going on. brains about to explode

Comment: you know, to be clear, when i add pagination functions for example, to page or single.php via the simple (next_posts_link or previeous_posts_link) etc, the DO work, what im wanting is that when i limit the post loop to say 2 posts per page, and there are say 10 posts in total, that the "1,2,3,4" that appears at the bottom of the page work. is this still considered pagination?

Comment: @somedow ok I think I may know the problem. In your archive-books.php or similar file before the loop make sure for you use the paged option. For example `$args = array( 'post_type' => 'books', 'posts_per_page' => 2, 'paged' => $paged  );` then start your loop after

Comment: that did it! YOURE THE MAN!!!!!!!!! been on this for a WHILE! lol. thank you very much for the contiinued support